# How do I map a component that has an array parameter in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm not sure how to properly type an array that contains objects. Sorry if this is worded poorly, let me know if you have any questions. Thank you!

```
const gamesPlayed = { id: 1, gamePlayedId: 1, completed: "2022-09-20T00:00:00.000Z", players: (2) [{ id: 1, score: 21, userId: 1, gameId: 1, guestName: "John Doe", id: 1, score: 21 },
{ id: 2, score: 20, userId: 2, gameId: 1, guestName: "Bob Doe", id: 2, score: 20}}


 {gamesPlayed?.players !== undefined &&
                gamesPlayed?.players.map(
                  (p1: Array<Object>, p2: Array<Object>) => ( //this line is where I'm struggling
                    <GameIconAndRecord
                      WinLoss={`${p1[0]?.score} / ${p2[1]?.score} `}
                    >
                      <EightBallIcon size="small" />
                    </GameIconAndRecord>
                  )
                )}
```

right now I'm getting the type error "Property 'score' does not exist on type 'Object'". I hard coded the "gamesPlayed" as a variable in this example, however it's actually coming from a database.

Comment: First, you should define a type for the elements of your array, something like `interface Player` with the appropriate properties.. Then you can do `Array<Player>`.

Comment: Also, you need to read more about how `map()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at your code, the problem comes from the way you're using `Array.prototype.map()` which only accepts 1 argument and here you're trying to pass in 2. Try this:

```
gamesPlayed?.players?.map(
  (player: Player) => (
    <GameIconAndRecord
      WinLoss={`${player.score}`}
    >
```

I'm assuming here that you have a Player interface declared. If not, you can take that part out.

Comment: Better yet, the OP should define `interface Player` if they haven't yet.

Comment: `map(...)` *can* pass two arguments, just second argument is index/`number`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what is your business problem to solve here, but i assume that you have to display component, which shows information about result of `game` played between two `players`:

```
const game = { 
    id: 1, 
    gamePlayedId: 1, 
    completed: "2022-09-20T00:00:00.000Z", 
    players: [{ 
        id: 1, 
        score: 21, 
        userId: 1, 
        gameId: 1, 
        guestName: "John Doe" 
    }, { 
        id: 2, 
        score: 20, 
        userId: 2, 
        gameId: 1, 
        guestName: "Bob Doe"
    }]
}
```

If it's the case, you don't need `map(...)` here:

```
 { (game && game.players) && 
    <GameIconAndRecord WinLoss={`${game.players[0]?.score} / ${game.players[1]?.score}`}>
        <EightBallIcon size="small" />
    </GameIconAndRecord> }
```